# Kivy button always showing on top of screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to create a button beneeth all other content in kivy. But the button is always showing on the top of the app, does anyone know how to solve this?

````
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Image:
            source: './assets/main_image.jpg'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: (root.width/1.5, root.height/3)
        Label:
            text: "Welkom bij de app \n \n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \n consectetur adipiscing elit. \n Curabitur tempus imperdiet commodo. \n Integer feugiat sollicitudin est, \n in auctor nibh mollis at."
            color: 0,0,0,1
            markup: True
        Button:
            text: 'press me'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 75, 50
           ```
````

Comment: Can you make the button invisible instead?

Comment: Why would i want to make the button invisible? I dont get it :)

Comment: I suppose if you put a button beneeth all other content, it is effectively not visible to your user, right? Most system should allow you to set visibility of a button rather easily.